# Chronology of Shofetim

Tags: product-recommendation, shoftim--book-of, literalism

Where can I find a diagram or timeline showing the chronology of the Shofetim according to different commentators?

For example Rashi on Shofetim 11:26, Ralbag nearby and Abarbanel on Shmuel 1 chapter 13 offer different opinions.

Modern scholars suggest the 40 years are non-literal or that the period of the judges coincided as they were in different areas of the country.

Answer (score -2):

The problem with the dateline of the Shoftim is essentially the last 2 stories of Pessel Michoh and Pilegesh Begivah in Perokim 17-18 and 19-21.

There is a Machloikes in the Meforshim if they actually happened straight after Yehoshua and before the first Shoifet Osniel Ben Kanaz but are put at the end of the Sefer  because we don't want to start Sefer Shoftim with such bad incidents or they did in fact happen after Shimshon and before Eli Hakoihen at the beginning of Shmuel Aleph and are in their correct place.

Since no one can be Machriya which of these 2 opinions are correct so there can be no accepted diagram or timeline of the Shoftim.

I would strongly recommend a very detailed analysis of the Shoftim in the Mikroois Gedoilois version from Machon Hamoar in Hebrew on their page Zayin with the subtitle Daled.Sidron Shel Shoftim I think its probably the basis for many other such lists that have come out since in the last 15 - 20 years or so.

Comment: The OP asked for “according to the different commentators,” so your claim that there’s an argument about the chronology is irrelevant.